# br not valid in ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists, w3c-validation

I have a navigation bar on my website.

**The HTML:**

```html
<nav id="navigation">
<a href="index.html"> <h1>My Cooking Webpage</h1> </a>
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="nav/recipes.html" class="right_categories">Recipes</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="nav/categories.html" class="right_categories">Categories</a>
        <ul id="subcategories">
            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="nav/about.html" class="right_categories">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**The CSS:**

```css
#navigation {
font-size: 24px;
float: right;
}
#featured-image {
    width: 800px;
    height: 600px;
}
.breadcrumb {
    font-size: 20px;
}
#subcategories {
display: none;
}
nav {
display: block;
position: relative;
}
nav li {
    display: block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    float: right;
}
nav li:hover #subcategories {
display: block;
}
nav a {
color: white;
}
nav ul {
padding: 0px;
list-style-type: none;
}
#featuredtext {
position: relative;
}
#page-background {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
position: relative;
z-index: 1;
    padding: 10px;
}
#slider_wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#navigation {
width: 100%;
}
```

My `DOCTYPE` is HTML5 (`<!DOCTYPE html>`) if that helps.

The problem is that when I hover over the "Categories" link, the drop-down box drops horizontally rather than vertically. When I put `<br />`s in between the `<li>`s, the HTML doesn't validate.

I think it is because of the `float: right;` in the CSS, though I tried to correct it with `float: none;`.

Is there a way to make it drop down vertically rather than horizontally, or is there an alternative to `<br />`. I want the HTML to validate through the W3C validators, [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) and [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only valid child element of a `<ul>` is a `<li>`. Style the `<li>`'s top and bottom margins using CSS to pad their vertical distance. Remove the `float` style altogether to have them appear as block elements lined up vertically.

Comment: how? `margin` and `padding` are the two things in CSS that confuse me

Comment: Margin adds space to the outside of the element. Padding adds space inside the element.

Comment: I used `float: none` and a bit of margin. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
nav li {
    display: block; <-- remove, this is already a block item
    margin-right: 10px; <-- move to your A tag declaration and also add display:block to your A tag
    float: right;  <-- remove, this is causing it to be horizontal
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify which declaration you were talking about in "move to your A tag declaration and also add display:block to your A tag"?

Comment: It actually doesn't work it made my right nav almost on top of my header.

Comment: I think I'll have to put my complete CSS. Should I?

Comment: I might as well put the whole thing. It's not that big.

Comment: I can't it says that jsfiddle is down to me, but [Down for everyone or just me says something else](http://www.isup.me/jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 0):

I optimized  your HTML and CSS in this way:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="sub">
        <a href="nav/recipes.html" class="right_categories">Recipes</a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub">
        <a href="nav/categories.html" class="right_categories">Categories</a>
        <ul id="subcategories">
            <li class="sub">
                <a href="#">Item 1</a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub">
                <a href="#">Item 2</a>
            </li>

            <li class="sub">
                <a href="#">Item 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub">
        <a href="nav/about.html" class="right_categories">About Us</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#ul
    {
            margin:0;
       padding:0;
    }

    ul.menu li
    {
        display:inline;
        position:relative;

    }

    li.sub > ul
    {
        display:none;
    }

    ul.menu li.sub:hover > ul
    {
        position:absolute;
        top:100%;
        left:0;
        display:block;
    }

    ul.menu ul li.sub:hover > ul
    {
        position:absolute;
        top:0;
        left:100%;
        display:block;
    }
```

Now it is true.

Comment: what it means? remove the tag  <nav id="navigation">

Comment: Why should I remove the `<nav>`?

Comment: i dont know what is your problem.i test this html and css sample and then post to you.try a little you can find the error. use firebug to debug.

Comment: I told you the problem, it is not valid HTML

Comment: copy this css and html to new html file and test it.