# Where I am doing wrong in writing PHP code?

Tags: php, html, loops, foreach

I am just trying to print list of cities, actually I have to store a result of loop in a variable. I am doing something wrong. It will be helpful, if somebody can correct it.

```
$list_of_cities = ['Delhi', 'Patna'];

$display = "<p>Cities</p><p><ul>". foreach($list_of_cities as $city) { ."<li>". $city . "</li><br>" . } . "</ul><p><a href='". get_site_url() . "/contact-us/'>Test</a></p>";
```

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong?  What specific problem are you observing?  What debugging have you done?  (Surely you're getting syntax errors on that second line...)

Comment: foreach($list_of_city as $city) { should be foreach($list_of_cities as $city) {

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'foreach' (T_FOREACH)

Comment: wait, you're trying to concat a foreach loop - you can't do that

Comment: You cannot use a foreach inside of a string like that. You'll need to complete your string, then you can use the foreach to append to it.

Comment: I have mistakenly written a second foreach loop

Comment: @JavedAkhtar: That loop is... all wrong.  You're mixing up control structures (in this case a loop) with assigning values.  Create an initial string.  Then in a loop append to that string.  Each statement is complete by itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot concat a `foreach()` loop, so do this, [concating `$display`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/80c859d78dec84e5aa3e556b8002c0e02b903034):

```
$list_of_cities = ['Delhi', 'Patna'];

$display = "<p>Cities</p><p><ul>";
foreach($list_of_cities as $city) {
    $display .= "<li>". $city . "</li>";
}
$display .= "</ul><p><a href='". get_site_url() . "/contact-us/'>Test</a></p>";

echo $display;
```

[line breaks are not valid in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763322/br-not-valid-in-ul)

Answer (score 1):

Many issues.

- You cannot have a foreach in a concatenation
- it is invalid HTML to have `<br>` after LIs
- typos in list_of_city
- only call get_site_url once

I assume you meant this:

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb9d1aae8dac86991bf9b9d3a2d730d10b589eff

```
<?php 
$list_of_cities = ['Delhi', 'Patna'];
$siteUrl = get_site_url();

$display = "<p>Cities</p><p><ul>";

foreach($list_of_cities as $city) { 
    $display.="<li>". $city . "</li>";
} 

$display.= "</ul><p><a href='". $siteUrl ."/contact-us/'>Test</a></p>";

foreach($list_of_cities as $city) {
   echo $city."<br>";
}
echo $display; 
?>
```

Comment: I was looking for citation on that, to give the OP more info. Do we both need to have more coffee and possibly a cinnamon roll?

Comment: Getting myself a coffee now